# TypeScript Record with inferable value type

Tags: typescript

How do I create a map which enforces that all keys are present on the map but at the same time allows inferring type of it's values?

If I have some keys, e.g.

```js
type State = "OPEN" | "CLOSED";
```

**Approach 1: using an untyped `object`**

```js
const stateToNaturalLangMap = {
  OPEN: "open",
  CLOSED: "closed"
} as const;

// "OPEN" | "CLOSED"
type KeysOfMap = keyof typeof stateToNaturalLangMap;

// "open" | "closed"
type ValuesOfMap = (typeof stateToNaturalLangMap)[keyof typeof stateToNaturalLangMap];
```

Approach 1 allows inferring types of keys and values, but does not enforce that all keys are part of the map (or additional keys are added).

**Approach 2: using `Record`**

```js
const stateToNaturalLangRecord: Record<State, string> = {
  OPEN: "open",
  CLOSED: "closed"
} as const;

// "OPEN" | "CLOSED"
type KeysOfRecord = keyof typeof stateToNaturalLangRecord;

// string
type ValuesOfRecord = (typeof stateToNaturalLangRecord)[keyof typeof stateToNaturalLangRecord];
```

Approach 2 is kind of the opposite: it enforces that all keys are part of the map (and does not allow other keys), but does not allow inferring type values (type of values is `string`).

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQCwQwNwKagM4HsC2SDWCCeyAaUBAOgHMSBYAKABdcAHJAZVplqQF5QAiAeQAKAUQByPUAB9eAYQAyfZkIAiPANw0aIUAAlUAd1AATVBFABjAE4J2SGKHQwGoPVACWZqMQB2AM1QWzBGRQWlhaUBgAG0jQHHwIq1AGK2QEL3DULxCoJAcnACMAV3D2bKRkGEwQ1yqoyP1gwwQLVzhXLzIQxiRUH1BXWgByYLgowqCAfg1qLUdk1BgPUABGAC4aM0zkcO2bABVUEXZCiyjZGA6AWUdQbgBvGlBQQVFV3lQmLx4CR9A5BWUbx4ZnqqUMPBoAF8IsFNl5tupqJowPxhGJJDJ5IoVDR6ExQABpPDIPg%20a5ObhxXpdJjU3YcA5HWgnM4XMjkxHI96fcRSYGghDg3HdUAANTGQVJ5NuoAAFHiEHS2AzDsdTpFzldHABKADaVL6CqV%201VzPVmvZjgAupyZmA5hYFktlhFog0jM1Wu1OgrgtS4sELoZQKNIuNCKAiuFjEFQF5UOE0n4AkhQqU6rFiQkkAwYBYMoacvZHNNZgx5otPAAmdbUOHbFDKhCMtWsjoAJQQmwshjene7hgAPKwbERti0OgA%20GUPahPF4iIEfNLfX7-bFAkGoMEQ6jQmCwra0W1aVGiXmYgE4ugion4Un9-zByl4alGvr05umlkatmPnsnmA47esK%20LimGko%20P%20z5yu%20jYmkyP4WtBeoGjSiofk2LZmm2ZDQTapb2uWjqVqAVb9MEoQ9OW24DAgbwDN4yaBJRYSujEAbZkkeYFmUxYMEQUZGKgsbxiUboGE0LRtB06EhhKyBAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [satisfies operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to:

- keep the precise type of your constant
- verify it conforms to `Record<State, string>` shape

```ts
type State = "OPEN" | "CLOSED";

const stateToNaturalLangRecord = {
  OPEN: "open",
  CLOSED: "closed"
} as const satisfies Record<State, string>;

// "OPEN" | "CLOSED"
type KeysOfRecord = keyof typeof stateToNaturalLangRecord;

type ValuesOfRecord = (typeof stateToNaturalLangRecord)[keyof typeof stateToNaturalLangRecord];
// type ValuesOfRecord = "open" | "closed"
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=21&pln=12&pc=1#code/PTAEElQCwQwNwKagM4HsC2SDWCCeyAaUBAOgHMSBYAKABdcAHJAZVplqQF5QAiAeQAKAUQByPUAB9eAYQAyfZkIAiPANw0aAY1QA7ZLRRsOAFVQj2AVwBOMADayYOsgCUE2qwBNQ3AN41QoIKiAFy8qEw6PAT%20oHIKyqE8mraoyAgePDQAvqAwyKDaegbI7ACWyABmpQj5ru4eADys7AhE%20lalTgB86tQ0ILxBYpIy8ooqNPRMoADSeMh8FXWont6gOLioFaBTCFuGLabmtNZ2Dk7Lnr2TjEgAanYWNYuXXtwAFLv7%20odmljb2RwuNwrDwASgA2ht9l9tj8TH8TgDzsD6gBdXoDAKgAB6AH4aEA)